# JS: Dynamically make second input required when the first input is given value?

Tags: javascript

Basically I have a row with a couple inputs, like this:

```
<div class="row collapse-col input-connect" id="custom-field-1">

    <div class="col small-4-10"><input type="text" placeholder="Item 1" name="custom_item_1" id="custom-item-1"></div>
    <div class="col small-3-10"><input type="number" min="0" max="99999.99" step="0.01" placeholder="Price 1" name="custom_amount_1" id="custom-amount-1"></div>

    <div class="col small-3-10"><select name="custom_type_1" id="custom-type-1"><option value="" selected>Options:</option><option value="optdiscount">No Discount</option></select></div>
</div>
```

I have a script that dynamically adds new rows, which isn't important to show, but just know that it will dynamically add rows so that "custom-field-1" becomes"custom-field-2" and on, and the same with "custom-item-2, "custom-amount-2", and the rest of the attributes that need to be updated. That's all done, that works fine.

**I want the "custom-amount-X" inputs to be 'required' if someone starts entering into the "custom-item-X" inputs.**

Here is what I have so far:

```
function formCustomFieldsAllow(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for (var i = 1; document.getElementById("custom-item-"+i); i++) {
        var itemEntered = document.getElementById("custom-item-"+i).value;
        if (itemEntered) {
            document.getElementById("custom-amount-"+i).required = true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("custom-amount-"+i).required = false;
        }
    }
}
document.getElementById('form-button-submit').addEventListener('change', formCustomFieldsAllow);
```

The idea is that the user clicks on the submit button, this will check to see if any custom-item's are filled and then see if their corrosponding custom-amount's are filled, if it doesn't find a match it will stop the form and make the appropriate custom-amount's 'required'.

My script doesn't work - any help would be appreciated?

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qa8s4qc4/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I'd suggest is the following:

```js
// the function bound as the event-handler for the 'input' event:
function conditionallyRequired(e) {
  // e is passed automatically as the first argument via the
  // EventTarget.addEventListener() method.

  // caching the element upon which the event was triggered:
  var trigger = e.target,

    // caching the element whose id is equivalent to that of the
    // trigger, with the 'item' portion of the id string replaced
    // with 'amount':
    target = document.getElementById(trigger.id.replace('item', 'amount'));

  // setting the required property of the target using an assessment to find
  // if the length of the trigger element's value, with leading and trailing
  // whitespace removed, is greater than zero; the strings '' and '     ' will
  // evaluate to false, whereas 'a' and '      a       ' will both evaluate
  // to true:
  target.required = trigger.value.trim().length > 0;
}

// because rows are added dynamically to the <form> we use event-delegation,
// and bind the event-handler to the ancestor <form> element, although if the
// <form> is loaded dynamically the EventTarget must be bound to the closest
// ancestor that is present in the document on page-load, or be dynamically bound
// when the <form> is added:
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('input', conditionallyRequired);
```

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.row .col {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
input,
div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
#form-button-submit {
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 40%;
  min-width: 20px;
}
[required] {
  /* adding a style to visually indicate
     a required <input> element; adjust
     to taste */
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="send_price" method="post" action="">

  <div class="row" id="custom-field-1">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Item 1" name="custom_item_1" id="custom-item-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="number" min="0" max="99999.99" step="0.01" placeholder="Price 1" name="custom_amount_1" id="custom-amount-1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="custom-field-2">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Item 2" name="custom_item_1" id="custom-item-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="number" min="0" max="99999.99" step="0.01" placeholder="Price 2" name="custom_amount_2" id="custom-amount-2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="form-button-submit">

</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/00fm5o85/).

References:

- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Comment: Hey David! I appreciate your reply, sorry I haven't had a chance to sit down since posting the question... I will take a look at this tomorrow. For now I will vote your answer up =)

Comment: I certainly appreciate the up-vote, and I absolutely hope this will help, but don't feel compelled to up-vote any answer(s) until you've verified that they work! Obviously, feel free to let me know about any problems and I'll take a look.

Comment: Actually, I just tested it now... this is flipping perfect! I do have a question... The only 2 references I haven't experienced yet are .replace() and trim() - so I get that you're caching the element with `var trigger = e.target`, but how does this work? Maybe you could give me a little insight when you have the time, if possible. I'm not very good with JS.

Comment: The linked references at the bottom of the answer should explain their use-case, and how to use them; but `String.replace('string1','string2')` will look at the String and find the first occurrence of 'string1' and replace it with 'string2'. `String.trim()` removes the leading, and trailing, whitespace so that `"   a   ".trim()` becomes `"a"`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've figured it out, here is what I've done:

```
  function formCustomFieldsAllow() {
    for (var i = 1; !!document.getElementById("custom-item-"+i); i++) {
      var itemEntered = document.getElementById("custom-item-"+i).value;
      if (itemEntered) {
        document.getElementById("custom-amount-"+i).required = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("custom-amount-"+i).required = false;
      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('form-button-submit').addEventListener('click', formCustomFieldsAllow);
```

I changed the eventlistener from change to click, changed the elementId in the for loop to a boolean, and got rid preventDefault.